# How to change a submit button class?

Tags: forms, class, cakephp, input

By default, when I'm calling submit button in CakePHP View like this:

```
echo $this->Form->end('Save');
```

The above will output:

```
<div class="submit">
     <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</div>
```

Bot I wan't it to be only this:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save"/>
```

I've searching the manual , but did not found anything interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
$options = array('label' => 'Save', 'class' => 'submit', 'div' => false);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```

Alternatively

```
echo $this->Form->button('Save', array('class' => 'submit'));
```

For more, see [this API entry](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperend)